# How do I get it out that only the user can change the node?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

You have to Imagine I have a node inside this node are comments(messages) and now I want the user who made the comment to be able to edit or even delete his own comment directly, but only the user who created it.
I honestly don't know if it works that way, but I hope someone can help me with this.

Edit: I add a deleteHandler.

```
function Messages({ forum }) {
  console.log(forum);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const messageList = useSelector((state) => state.messageList);
  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const { userInfo } = userLogin;
  const { messages } = messageList;

  const handleClick = async () => {
    const finalMessage = `${userInfo.userName}: ${message}`;
    await dispatch(createMessageAction(forum._id, finalMessage));
    dispatch(listMessage());
    setMessage("");
  };

  const deleteHandler = (id) => {
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure? you want to delete")) {
      dispatch(deleteMessageAction(id));
    }
   };

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listMessage());
  }, []);

  console.log(messages);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.messagesOuterContainer}>
        <div className={classes.messagesInnerContainer}>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h6">
            Comments
          </Typography>
          {messages
            ?.filter((message) => message.forumID === forum._id)
            ?.map((c) => (
              <Typography key={c._id} gutterBottom variant="subtitle1">
                <strong>{c.messageText} </strong>
                <EditIcon />
                <IconButton aria-label="delete">
                  <DeleteIcon onClick={() => deleteHandler(message._id)}/>
                </IconButton>
              </Typography>
            ))}
        </div>
        {userInfo?.userName && (
          <div style={{ width: "70%" }}>
            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h6">
              Comments
            </Typography>
            <TextField
              fullwidth="false"
              rows={4}
              variant="outlined"
              label="add a Comment"
              multiline
              value={message}
              onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Button
              style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}
              fullwidth="false"
              disabled={!message}
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              onClick={handleClick}
            >
              Send
            </Button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

My MessageList state:

```
>messageList
 >messages
   >0: {_id:"....", forumID:"..", messageText:"...", user:".."
   >1: .....
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have information about the author of the comment. Assuming each entry in `messages` has that information, create a conditional that checks to see if the current user's id is the same as the message's author id.

Something along the lines of this.

```js
{messages
    ?.filter((message) => message.forumID === forum._id)
    ?.map((c) => (
        <Typography key={c._id} gutterBottom variant="subtitle1">
        <strong>{c.messageText} </strong>
        {message.userId === userLogin.id && ( // modify keys names accordingly
            <>
                <EditIcon />
                <IconButton aria-label="delete">
                    <DeleteIcon />
                </IconButton>
        </>
        )}
        </Typography>
    ))}
```

Comment: I got a syntax error .. SyntaxError: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>?

Comment: @basics_ Ah, yes. My mistake. Let me fix that.

Comment: I have to put </> over </Typography> then it is working .. but thanks for first I have to find out now.. how this should be run successfully I tried this but it doesn´t show me the icons.. message._id === userInfo._id

Comment: @basics_ Yikes, fixed that. `console.log`  both `message._id` and `userInfo._id` and see what the values are. Maybe one is a number and the other is a string?

Comment: console.log(message._id) is undefined and console.log(userInfo._id) is the id of the user

Comment: @basics_ Check the entire `message` object. If the user id does not exist in it, you need to add it as part of your backend response

Comment: its existing I can edit my state so you can understand better but I tried it it doesn´t work .. :/

Comment: Did you checked my state In my post ?

Comment: @basics_ Basically, you need to have your conditional to evaluate to `true` if the user is the author of the comment. I think I've given you all of the information to figure this out on your own. This is a good time to learn how to implement this concept yourself. It's a very common thing implement in FE projects

Comment: I will do my Best thanks.